# Distinct results from dynamic dropdown

Tags: mysql, forms

I am displaying information from a query that basically filters through options from a form.  That query is:

```
`SELECT bp.*, b.company 
FROM `windows_brands_products` bp 
LEFT JOIN `windows_brands` b 
ON bp.brand_id = b.id 
JOIN Windows_last_submissions ls 
JOIN windows_materials wm 
WHERE bp.width = ROUND(ls.width) 
AND bp.height = ROUND(ls.height) 
AND bp.material IN (wm.name) 
AND bp.type = ls.type 
AND IF (ls.minimumbid != '0.00',bp.cost BETWEEN ls.minimumbid AND ls.maximumbid,bp.cost <= ls.maximumbid)`
```

I am also populating a dropdown menu from another table in that database called 'materials_list' dynamically from a view, which is queried:

```
`SELECT b.company
FROM `windows_brands_products` bp 
LEFT JOIN `windows_brands` b 
ON bp.brand_id = b.id 
JOIN Windows_last_submissions ls 
JOIN windows_materials wm 
WHERE bp.width = ROUND(ls.width) 
AND bp.height = ROUND(ls.height) 
AND bp.material IN (wm.name) 
AND bp.type = ls.type 
AND IF (ls.minimumbid != '0.00',bp.cost BETWEEN ls.minimumbid AND ls.maximumbid,bp.cost <= ls.maximumbid)`
```

That query produces only the company names but it still repeats.

because I want that list to display the field 'company' from the above query.  So say 5 different companies come up as part of that query, I want the dropdown to show those 5 different companies.  In many cases, the query will result in multiple companies because the other parameters (material,type,cost) can be different for the same company - so I'd have 2 or more of the same company show up..and it populates the dropdown that way (repeating some of the company names).  How can I make it so that any company showing in the dropdown will be unique?

Comment: `GROUP BY b.company`?

Comment: Works!  I need to learn about GROUP BY a bit.  I also need the same thing for materials.  How would I go about that?  When I group by both it shows one result only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `group by` -

```
SELECT b.company
FROM `windows_brands_products` bp 
LEFT JOIN `windows_brands` b ON bp.brand_id = b.id 
JOIN Windows_last_submissions ls 
JOIN windows_materials wm 
WHERE bp.width = ROUND(ls.width) 
    AND bp.height = ROUND(ls.height) 
    AND bp.material IN (wm.name) 
    AND bp.type = ls.type 
    AND IF (ls.minimumbid != '0.00',bp.cost BETWEEN ls.minimumbid AND ls.maximumbid,bp.cost <= ls.maximumbid) 
GROUP By b.company
```